# python chr (minus) value

Tags: python, ascii, chr

please help.
python:

> > > chr(-155)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)

minus value is error to return a specific character ASCII
how resolve that problem?
Thank you (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Why did you expect this to work?

Comment: Could you please provide your code and data? Then, someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

The integers representing ASCII characters are all positive. A negative integer does not have an equivalent ASCII character. See [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/) for a table of valid ASCII characters.

So the real problem is that your program is accepting improper input. You need to check your input for [sanity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/92124) before attempting to process it.